# Using encrypted password for database connection in spring boot application through spring auto configuration

Tags: spring-boot, jasypt

### Trying to use encrypted database password to connect to database using spring auto configuration

I am using Spring auto configuration to connect to database. For that i added below properties in properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ABCDE2D.com:1888:ABCDE2D1
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

In my dao class, i have @Autowired NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and using it directly to get data from database.

> Till here it is working fine.

Now i need to encrypt the password in properties file.
For that i did the below:

> 1. Added jasypt-spring-boot-starter in pom
> 2. Added spring.datasource.password=ENC(NoIv2c+WQYF3LenN0tDYPA==) in properties file
> 3. Added jasypt.encryptor.password=key in properties file

Now i am getting the below error:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.password' to  
java.lang.String:
Reason: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.password' to   
java.lang.String
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace

Comment: And another question. Why do you want to encrypt the password? It's worthless as you add the encryptor password to the properties file as well

Comment: have you added oracle dependency? please add your pom file..

Comment: @SimonMartinelli : i have added in properties file for now. Once it will running file i will pass the key as environment variable.

Comment: And so follows the next stupid question: Why don't you just define the database password as environment variable? So can get rid of jasypt at all

Comment: Yes this seems to be a good option. Didnt thought of this.

Comment: Anyway if for some reason i wanted to do what i was trying earlier.. how can i do that

Comment: What if I keep the actual encrypted password in properties file and pass Jasypt password as environment variable and delete from environment once the application is started

Answer (score 16):

I'm providing some basic guide as follows.

You need to add following two parameters in to property file in order application to work properly. This is assuming you are encrypting using default encryption algorithm. If you are useing some other, then make sure to change it accordingly.

**jasypt.encryptor.iv-generator-classname=org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator
jasypt.encryptor.algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES**

You can refer to more details 
https://nirmalbalasooriya.blogspot.com/2020/02/spring-boot-property-encryption-using.html

Comment: How to make it working with default algorithm? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77788336/how-to-change-jasypt-algorithm-in-spring-boot-application-why-doesnt-it-work-w

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was giving wrong jasypt.encryptor.password.
For Example given below is properties I have set in my application.properties:

```
jasypt.encryptor.password=abc
```

instead abc I gave jasypt as my secret key while encrypting the password so the encripted password is wrong. Then it throwing this error.
Later I realised and found that the key is not correct.
Then gave the right key i.e., abc.Then it worked for me.
Silly mistake but it cost me 4 hours. Hope it will be useful for others.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **jasypt** dependency, make sure that:

```
spring.datasource.password = Enc
```

and

```
jasypt.encryptor.password = key
```

where ***Enc*** is encrypted password and ***key*** is the key which you used to generate the encrypted password.