# Connecting to MySQL using application.yml

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring boot and mysql. I am trying to create an REST API with mysql config in the application.yml file. My yml file is shown below.

```
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    username:
    password:
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
```

The problem is that I don't want to put my password in the yaml file. I want to use a key file or a bearer token. I am not sure how I can start with this. Please help. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: You could give jasypt a try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56579295/using-encrypted-password-for-database-connection-in-spring-boot-application-thro

Answer (score 2):

you can use Jasypt here to encrypt the DB password. and you can put it with **ENC()** key:--

```
spring:
datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    username:ENC(<incrypted username>)   // if you want
    password:ENC(<encrypted password>)
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
```

J**asypt POM dependency for spring-boot:--**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot-starter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

(For projects not using @SpringBootApplication or @EnableAutoConfiguration, then you can use the jasypt-spring-boot dependency directly)
**Others:--**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Wanna learn how encrypt/decrypt Jasypt key click: [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/cli.html)

more deatail about Jasypt [jasypt github](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0):

The **new** driver class is - **com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver**