# How to change jasypt algorithm in spring-boot application? why doesn't it work with default values?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jce, jasypt

In my Spring boot app I have following **application.yml** file:

```
jasypt:
  encryptor:
    password: secretKey
    algorithm: "PBEWithMD5AndDES"
    iv-generator-classname: org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator
 my:
   ldap:
     user: CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com
     password: ENC(ObIbZYSJF60VnboZMRtlhj9a/+4B/kkP)
```

**Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties::class)
class MyConfig(
    private val myProperties: MyProperties,
) {...}
```

========================

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.ldap")
data class MyProperties(
   password: String
)
```

The **setup above is fully working** but if I want to change algorithm:

```
jasypt:
  encryptor:
    password: secretKey
    iv-generator-classname: org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator
```

Or both (generator and algorithm )

```
 jasypt:
   encryptor:
     password: secretKey
```

So will be used default algorithm `PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_256` and `org.jasypt.iv.RandomIvGenerator` but I receive an error:

> Failed to bind properties under 'my.ldap.password' to
> java.lang.String:
>
> ```
> Property: my.ldap.user
> Value: "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com"
> Origin: class path resource [application-local.yaml] - 5:11
> Reason: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed
> ```
>
> to bind properties under 'my.ldap.password' to
> java.lang.String

[image]
https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot

Based on table above I expected that I have to provide a **single** parameter

```
jasypt.encryptor.password
```

but it doesn't work.

Why does it happen ?

Comment: You also setup `jasypt` programmatically using java/kotlin which is the best approach especially when your password has special characters

Comment: @Eric thank you but I am not sure your answer adresses my question

Comment: Setting `jasypt` properties programmatically enables you use default encryption algorithm or specify encryption algorithm you need

Comment: @Eric my question why doesn't it work with default settings(with default algorithm) without additional settings ? What should I do to use default algorithm ?

Comment: Not sure why it isn't working when you configure in `application.yml`. Personally I configure `jasypt` programmatically which allows to use default or specific algorithm without any problem. Maybe you  can try programmatically too